# Check if an array of CKRecords contains a certain record

Tags: ios, swift, ckrecord

In my app I have got hundreds of movie objects as `CKRecord`s that is being put in an array after retrieving them. I would, for example, like a way to check if the array contains a movie record with the title "Titanic".

What I have done up till now, is looping trough the array like this:

```
for movie in (movies as NSArray as! [CKRecord]) {
    if movie.objectForKey("Title") as? String == "Titanic" {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
if movies.contains(CKRecord.whereKey"Title" == "Titanic") {
   // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a filter in the array, for example:

```
let filteredArray = movies.filter() {
    if let title = ($0 as PFObject)["Title"] as String {
        return type.rangeOfString("example") != nil
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways we can proceed with this:

1 Approach: Using NSpredicate

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Title = 'Titanic'")
let movie = (movies as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate) as! NSArray
```

Then we can check the count of array for presence of object.

2. Using Filter function as give by @Exequiel above